# Calculating Factorials using QBasic

Tags: qbasic

I'm writing a program that calculates the Factorial of 5 numbers and output the results in a Tabular form but I keep getting **Zeros**.

**Factorial Formula:**. *n! = n×(n-1)!*

I tried:

```
CLS
DIM arr(5) AS INTEGER

FOR x = 1 TO 5
    INPUT "Enter Factors: ", n
NEXT x

f = 1
FOR i = 1 TO arr(n)
    f = f * i
NEXT i

PRINT
PRINT "The factorial of input numbers are:";
PRINT

FOR x = 1 TO n
    PRINT f(x)
NEXT x
END
```

and I'm expecting:

```
Numbers    Factorrials
5          120
3          6
6          720
8          40320
4          24
```

Answer (score 1):

You did some mistakes

```
FOR i = 1 TO arr(n)
```

where is n defined
you also never stored actual values into arr

```
PRINT f(x)
```

here you take from array f that is also not defined in your code

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a BASIC interpreter right in front of me, but I think this is what you're looking for:

```
CLS
DIM arr(5) AS INTEGER
DIM ans(5) AS LONG        'You need a separate array to store results in. 

FOR x = 1 TO 5
    INPUT "Enter Factors: ", arr(x)
NEXT x

FOR x = 1 to 5
    f& = 1
    FOR i = 1 TO arr(x)
        f& = f& * i
    NEXT i
    ans(x) = f&
NEXT x

PRINT
PRINT "The factorial of input numbers are:";
PRINT

PRINT "Numbers", "Factorials"
FOR x = 1 TO 5
    PRINT STR$(arr(x)), ans(x)
NEXT x
END
```

Just a comment though: In programming, you should avoid reusing variables unless you are short on memory. It can be done right, but it creates many opportunities for hard to find bugs in larger programs.

Comment: You forgot to store the f result into the ans() array.

Comment: Your factors are under **Numbers** instead of **Factors** and there is a negative value among the them which isn't correct. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: @SafianuMohammed Thanks. I shouldn't have tried answering it without an interpreter in front of me.

Comment: That was very brilliant, you correct some mistakes without interpreter meaning you're very good, I respect that.

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of the answers as an accepted answer. @eoredson and myself both have answers that are appropriate to select for this. It helps us and helps future people looking for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution to calculate arrays of factorials:

```
CLS
DIM arr(5) AS INTEGER
DIM ans(5) AS LONG

FOR x = 1 TO 5
    INPUT "Enter Factors: ", arr(x)
    f& = 1
    FOR i = 1 TO arr(x)
        f& = f& * i
    NEXT i
    ans(x) = f&
NEXT x

PRINT
PRINT "The factorial of input numbers are:";
PRINT

PRINT "Numbers", "Factorials"
FOR x = 1 TO 5
    PRINT arr(x), ans(x)
NEXT x
END
```

Comment: Now this is precisely the ANSWER, Thanks

Comment: Since factorials grow large very quickly, the long type will overflow to 0. The solution would be to dim ans() as double and increment f& to f#..

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution to calculate arrays of factorials and square roots:

```
CLS
PRINT "Number of values";: INPUT n
DIM arr(n) AS INTEGER
DIM ans(n) AS LONG

FOR x = 1 TO n
    PRINT "Enter value"; x;: INPUT arr(x)
    f& = 1
    FOR i = 1 TO arr(x)
        f& = f& * i
    NEXT i
    ans(x) = f&
NEXT x

PRINT
PRINT "The factorial/square root of input numbers are:";
PRINT

PRINT "Number", "Factorial", "Squareroot"
FOR x = 1 TO n
    PRINT arr(x), ans(x), SQR(arr(x))
NEXT x
END
```

Comment: I just thought adding the square root would be cute :)